# Programmatically Added OLEbject (OptionButton) not clickable (PowerPoint VBA)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am building slides with VBA adding optionbuttons and checkboxes, however these are not 'clickable' when added whilst in presentation mode. If the option button exists on the slide in normal view and then I enter presentation view on that slide, the option button is clickable after a fraction of a second. It appears as if the option button is loaded initially as a picture and then changes to an actionable object (the resolution also improves) almost instantaneously.

If the option button is added whilst already in presentation view then the object remains almost as an image and is not clickable.

I can see something is happening when I enter presentation mode if the optionbutton already exists on the slide but I don't know how to replicate it in VBA, it's almost as if I need to refresh the slide or activate the option buttons as objects.

I am adding the option buttons like this:

```
Set newCtrl = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.AddOLEObject(ClassName:="Forms.OptionButton.1")

        With newCtrl.OLEFormat.Object
            .Height = 30
            .Top = 150
            .Left = 150
            .Width = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 80 - .Left
            .Caption = "Some Caption"
            .BackStyle = 0
        End With
```

Comment: In addition I've noticed that setting the presentation to white/black screen and then back to normal also allows the option buttons to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really an answer, more of a workaround but as per my comment above the following allows the option buttons to be clicked after they have been added.

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.State = ppSlideShowBlackScreen
SlideShowWindows(1).View.State = ppSlideShowRunning
```